# Как правильно написать код хода компьютера

Tags: javascript

Написал игру крестики нолики, для двоих игроков, а вот как реализовать ход компьютера, что-то в голову адекватные идеи не приходят. Подскажите от чего отталкиваться, возможно фрагменты кода полезные. Буду очень благодарен!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    document.querySelector('.game').innerHTML += '<div class="block"></div>';
  }
  var step = 0;

  var arr = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6]
  ];

  document.querySelector('.game').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.className == 'block' && e.target.textContent == '') {
      if (step % 2 == 0) {
        e.target.appendChild(paintX());
      } else {
        e.target.appendChild(paintO());
      }
      step++;
      checkWinner();
    }
  });

  var checkWinner = function() {
    var count = 0;
    var winner = '';
    var allBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

    for (var i = 0; i < allBlock.length - 1; i++) {
      if (allBlock[arr[i][0]].innerHTML == allBlock[arr[i][1]].innerHTML && allBlock[arr[i][1]].innerHTML == allBlock[arr[i][2]].innerHTML && allBlock[arr[i][0]].innerHTML != '') {
        for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
          allBlock[arr[i][j]].style.animation = 'blink .15s infinite alternate';
        }
        winner = allBlock[arr[i][0]].firstElementChild.getAttribute('data-value');
        count++;
      }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
      finishGame(winner);
    } else if (step == 9 & count == 0) {
      draw();
    }
  };

  function reset() {
    var allBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

    for (var i = 0; i < allBlock.length; i++) {
      allBlock[i].textContent = '';
      allBlock[i].style.animation = '';
    }
    step = 0;
  };

  function paintX() {
    var wrapperX = document.createElement('span');
    wrapperX.setAttribute('data-value', 'X');
    wrapperX.classList.add('paintX');

    var firstLine = document.createElement('span');
    firstLine.classList.add('l1');
    var secondLine = document.createElement('span');
    secondLine.classList.add('l2');

    wrapperX.appendChild(firstLine);
    wrapperX.appendChild(secondLine);

    return wrapperX;
  };

  function paintO() {
    var wrapperO = document.createElement('span');
    wrapperO.setAttribute('data-value', 'O');
    wrapperO.classList.add('paintO');

    var elemO = document.createElement('span');
    elemO.classList.add('elemO');

    wrapperO.appendChild(elemO);

    return wrapperO;
  }

  function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Ничья')
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(reset, 200);
  };

  function finishGame(player) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert(player + ' победили')
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(reset, 200);
  };
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(../bg.jpeg) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -o-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.game {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.paintX,
.paintO {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.l1 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.l2 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.elemO {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: .3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="game"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну все просто: пишите простенький ИИ, тренируете его на 1000-2000x игр и все) вот тут либы https://proglib.io/p/ml-js/

Comment: я бы начал с написания случайного хода, а потом бы пробовал совершенствовать

Comment: @ThisMan норм вариант )))

Comment: ThisMan, тут я пытался спросить, как второй ход делать автоматически после первого. с ии я потом что-то придумаю.

Comment: Смотря чего хотим. Если я правильно помню, то есть самый эффективный алгоритм игры в крестики-нолики. Можете его зафигачить. Если хотите - можете рандом сделать.

Comment: A K, мне все равно какой будет алгоритм хода у ИИ, главное чтобы он делал ход после моего. Вот как это реализовать я и не пойму